# how to detect outliers from residual plot?

Tags: r, outliers, residuals

I have the following residual plot. Can I detect outliers from residual plot? 
I want to remove 200 outliers in my data set, but I do not know how should I do that in R ?

residual plots:

[image]

scatter plots:

[image]

Comment: That plot is difficult to read. I read it as implying that you have one (1) outlier, or rather there is one outlying point on the graph, which might represent arbitrarily many tied observations. The idea that you know you should remove 200 outliers in advance is eerily like the idea that you know before investigation that 200 people are guilty of trying to undermine a state.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How can I detect what is that outlier? is there a code in R that shows what that outlier is?

Comment: We now have 11 plots that are difficult to read. Still looks like one (1) outlier, as above. It should be easy to identify as having e.g. the largest negative residual.

Comment: If you know how many outliers you have (200, though I don't know how you could know that) and you have some definite criterion for what makes an observation more outlying than another, then you simply order the observations by that criterion and take the 200 largest ones. So what do you mean by 'outlier'? Define that only well enough to order the observations and you seem to be done.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. When I write this code : NegAdvSqrtIncome.mod<-lm(NegAdvSqrtIncome~ LogAssets+NegAdvInvest+AdvLogDelinq+LogCMembers+NegAdvSqrtBranches, data=HW3) and residualPlots(NegAdvSqrtIncome.mod,  id.n=3) and  qqPlot(NegAdvSqrtIncome.mod, id.n=3)it tags the outliers with numbers (5270 5925 7687 )! what are these numbers? my dependent variable does not have these values.

Comment: Those numbers are the identifiers of the "outlying" points.  Usually they are row numbers in a data matrix or dataframe.  They are provided because it is a bad idea automatically to remove these rows: by means of the identifiers you can inspect those rows and *thoughtfully consider* how to treat them in subsequent analyses.

Comment: @whuber Thank you very much. Then I should find a command to remove those rows.

Answer (score 6):

In general you can define outliers differently, depending on what exactly you are trying to achieve. For example, a presence of observations with very high leverage won't necessarily indicate that they are effecting the regression at all. On the other hand, presence of values with high Cook Distance, can certainly do. It is also possible that some values will have both. High Studentized residuals can indicate Heteroscedasticity. Here's an illustration of how you can identify/inspect each when compared to your original data and fitted regression line

Create some dummy data set and fit a linear regression model

```
set.seed(11)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(200), y = rnorm(200, 10, 5))
fit <- lm(y ~ x, data = df)
# summary(fit)
```

We will use `influencePlot` from `car` package in order to identify outliers and plot them, when

1. x axis are hat values
2. y axis are Studentized residuals
3. Circles representing the observations proportional to Cooks
       distances

   ```
   library(car)
   (outs <- influencePlot(fit))
   #        StudRes         Hat      CookD
   # 62  -2.3075152 0.035229039 0.30844382
   # 73   2.7848421 0.008209828 0.17618044
   # 196  0.5258255 0.047410106 0.08310058
   ```

[image]

Now, we can get the corresponding row names of the, for example, 2 highest values in each

```
n <- 2
Cooksdist <- as.numeric(tail(row.names(outs[order(outs$CookD), ]), n))
Lev <- as.numeric(tail(row.names(outs[order(outs$Hat), ]), n))
StdRes <- as.numeric(tail(row.names(outs[order(outs$StudRes), ]), n))
```

And plot them over the fitted regression line

```
plot(df$x, df$y)
abline(fit, col = "blue")
points(df$x[Cooksdist], df$y[Cooksdist], col = "red", pch = 0, lwd = 15)
points(df$x[Lev], df$y[Lev], col = "blue", pch = 25, lwd = 8)
points(df$x[StdRes], df$y[StdRes], col = "green", pch = 20, lwd = 5)
text(df$x[as.numeric(row.names(outs))], 
     df$y[as.numeric(row.names(outs))], 
     labels = round(df$y[as.numeric(row.names(outs))], 3),
     pos = 1)
```

[image]

You can clearly see that some of the outliers are overlapping, when the leverage ones (the blue triangles) can sometimes affect the regression line while in other occasions be almost on it, while the red squares (Cook Distance) always have high effect on the regression line.

Comment: What is the meaning of the points that `influencePlot(fit)` point out? Some have large Cook's distance but others don't how do you interpret this?

Comment: @tbone they are proportional to Cooks Distance. Try `res <- influencePlot(fit, id.n = 2) ; res[order(-res[, "CookD"]), "CookD", drop = FALSE]` and compare to the plot.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. So identified points are not proportional to Cook's distance? I just want to understand why they are flagged.

Comment: @tbone it returns the value(s) (depending on `id.n`) with the highest CookD, the highest Hat and the highest STDRes (while adding all the rest of the values). See `setNames(c(max(cooks.distance(fit)), max(abs(rstudent(fit))), max(hatvalues(fit))), c(which.max(cooks.distance(fit)), which.max(abs(rstudent(fit))), which.max(hatvalues(fit))))`

Comment: Ahh, got it now, so it flags the point(s) with the highest Cook distance, the highest estimated value (fitted value / hat value) and the highest studentized residual.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find the 200 most extreme points, you might do a z score transformation to see which have the highest |z|.  A rough guide is to look at |z|>3.

But I echo @Nick Cox .  In decades of statistical practice I've never been in a situation where I knew how many outliers there were.

Comment: Thank you.What is your recommendation? I do not know how to determine outliers? and how to remove them? I would be very thankful if you help