# Getting significant data from graph

Tags: statistical-significance

Currently I'm working on a project where I'm looking for similarities between files.

**Problem representation:**

I have 13K files.
Data are tokenized and every token has got it's type. Tokens represent parts of programming codes and one token can be a where clause (assigned type 5), then there will be a for loop(assigned type 3) or some other logical bunch of lines. So one file will be a list of integers representing code. Currently I do not care about what exactly is in the code, but I'm trying to recognise the structure of the file, so one integer is enough for a token.

I'm looking for similar token orders[e.g. 15 token types in multiple files have the same order], so I can consider it to be similar.

I already evaluated the data and gave it into graph:
[image]

X-axis is log(length of identical token order) and Y-axis log(how many times the order appeared in some files). I the top right corner you can see (number of different orders)/ (number of orders above the line).

**Question:**

I couldn't find algorithmic way of evaluating the data line other than empirical trying.

But I would like to find exact number of significant points. Currently I see an option to make a constant from a slope a just shift it to the left/ right based on number of points above the line(I would always like to find 80-100 points) and resizing the step size of shifting the line until I'll end in the range of points I would like to achieve.

I'm new to statistics and data analysis. **What is the best way to set the slope of the line?**
Currently I'm doing it as taking point of the highest quantity and point with the longest similarity and set a line between them (in the picture the line is multiplied by different constants). Is it the way it is normally done?

I was also thinking about normalizing the axis, make the slope 45 degree and just shift the line?
**How is it done by regular data analysist?**

Comment: Hi Juraj. Could explain (in the post) what "Data are tokenized" means?

Comment: @utobi  text edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, when you write

> Currently I'm doing it as taking point of the highest quantity and point with the longest similarity and set a line between them (in the picture the line is multiplied by different constants).

then you mean that you are discarding all data points with the same x-value except for the one with the highest y-value, and then somehow you determine a line through the remaining data points. If my understanding is correct, then the answer to you question

> Is it the way it is normally done?

is clearly: no, not at all. In data analysis, throwing away data points without good reason (e.g., large measurement errors in specific observations, impossible values) is never recommended. Typically, one would rather try to find a function (linear or non-linear) that fits well to *all* data. Commonly, the conditional mean of the response variable (the one on the y-axis) is modelled by one or several predictors.

Regarding your question

> What is the best way to set the slope of the line?

the answer is usually linear regression ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression)). If the assumption of a linear regression is met, the resulting estimator is the best linear unbiased estimator (BLUE).

However, I am not convinced that linear regression is necessarily a good, or even the best, choice to analyze the data you have. I had troubles to understand your questions, partly because you were using some words in a context that I could not make sense of, e.g. "token", "integer", "similar", "empirical trying".

Nevertheless I would like to give it a shot: **if your goal is to find the data points with the highest quantity relative to their length** (please confirm), you could simply calculate the ratio between quantity and length for each data point and then take the 100 highest ratios. I do not see a requirement to do any more complex statistical modeling. If this is indeed your goal, and you would like to learn statistical techniques to do this, you could search for "outlier detection". One popular method for example to identify outliers in a multi-dimensional space is the Mahalanobis distance.

Comment: No, I'm not discarding any data. I keep all of the data. To the linear regression - I want just few outliers, so maybe if could be done, by computing linear regression of the data - which will produce the slope and then take 100 points with the biggest distance to the line which are above it (is it used sometimes like that?).

Comment: About outlier/anomaly detection, I understand it, as detecting points which doesn't belong to the group, but here, I do not have any groups, the points can be next to each other in the graph, but in reality they are probably really different. But not I like the idea of using linear regression for defining the slope and ... As I mentioned comment above.

Comment: Last question: how would you like to count ratio? len*quantity(it's not a ratio, but I'm a bit confused)

Comment: @Juraj yes, you can use linear regression to identify outliers. How to do this in R is for example explained here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117873/how-to-detect-outliers-from-residual-plot. But it feels a bit strange, because what is then defined as an outlier depends on the outliers themselves. Have a look at this plot: https://ouzhang.me/blog/outlier-series/outliers-part3/figure/example1-1.png. The outliers heavily influence the fit so they are largely influencing the definition of an outlier.

Comment: @Juraj a suitable ratio would be $\text{quantity}/\text{length}$ or $\log(\text{quantity})/\log(\text{length})$. You say, you are not discarding any data, but in your plot it looks like the red line is driven only by $max(y|x)$. So maybe I am still not understanding your question entirely, sorry.